# How to query for all sub-categories containing a product (directly in sub-category, or anywhere down the category-tree, eg. in sub-sub category)?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql, nested-sets, query-builder

#### Schema:

> **Category [** `id`, `parent`, `children`, `left`, `right`, `level`, `root`, `products` **]**
>
> **Product [** `id`, `category`, `marketSegments` **]**
>
> **MarketSegment [** `id` **]**
>
> *Also each entity has fields like* `name`*,* `description`*,* `slug` *but those are not relevant to my issue.*

#### Example data

Legend:

`c` - Category, `p` - Product

Products marked with * are tagged with market segment "Export to USA"

```
Food                                [c, id: 1, level: 0]
---> Vegetables                       [c, id: 2, level: 1]
--------------> Potato                  [p, id: 1]
--------------> Carrot                  [p, id: 2]
---> Fruits                           [c, id: 3, level: 1]
--------------> Berries                 [c, id: 5, level: 2]
---------------------------> Grapes       [p, id: 3]
--------------> Hesperidiums            [c, id: 6, level: 2]
---------------------------> Orange*      [p, id: 4]
---> Meat                             [c, id: 4, level: 1]
--------------> Beef*                   [p, id: 5]
```

#### Expected query result:

For given data and **$category** = *Food*, **$marketSegment** = *Export to USA* the expected result would be:

`$filteredCategories = [Fruits, Meat]`

Why?

- `Meat` becouse it contains product `Beef` which is tagged with *Export to USA*
- `Fruits` becouse it contains category `Hesperidiums` which contains a tagged product.

It does not matter how deep in the nested tree the category containing tagged product is.

This:

```
Sports [c]
-----> Individual [c]
----------------> Fight [c]
----------------------> MMA [c]
--------------------------> Boxing gloves* [p]
```

For **$category** = *Sports* should return: [ `Individual` ].

For **$category** = *Fight* should return: [ `MMA` ].

---

#### My (not working) DQL approach:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cat FROM Avocode\CatalogBundle\Entity\Category cat 
WHERE cat.parent = :parent_id 
AND (EXISTS(
        SELECT sub FROM Avocode\CatalogBundle\Entity\Category sub 
        LEFT JOIN sub.products prod 
        LEFT JOIN prod.marketSegments seg 
        WHERE sub.left > cat.left 
        AND sub.right < cat.right 
        AND seg.id = :segment_id
)) 
ORDER BY cat.root, cat.left ASC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NestedTreeRepository` that ships with the Gedmo NestedSet behavior extension has a method `getChildrenQueryBuilder()` that allows you to query for children given a parent node, and has a parameter for querying for nodes that are several layers deep in the hierarchy. You should investigate methods and options that ship with `NestedTreeRepository` so as not need to build the DQL by hand.

I'm not entirely sure how all of your code is setup so I can't offer an exact solution but I think you can figure it out :)

NestedSet documentation: http://www.gediminasm.org/article/tree-nestedset-behavior-extension-for-doctrine-2

Answer (score 1):

Thank you John! Useing NestedTreeRepository I figured out the solution:

I created my own Repository for Category class that extends NestedTreeRepository and created a custom method

> public function findSubcategoriesFilteredByMarketSegment (Category $parentNode, MarketSegment $segment)
>
> {
>
> ```
>    // get DIRECT CHILDREN for $parentNode
>    $qb = $this->getChildrenQueryBuilder($parentNode, true);
>    $qb->leftJoin($qb->getRootAlias().'.products', 'prod')
>       ->leftJoin('prod.marketSegments', 'seg');    
>
>    // subquery -> get all children (direct and indirect) 
>    // for DIRECT CHILD from main query
>    $sqb = $this->_em->getRepository('AvocodeCatalogBundle:Category')->createQueryBuilder('sub');
>
>    // join products and market segments
>    $sqb->leftJoin($sqb->getRootAlias().'.products', 'sub_prod')
>        ->leftJoin('sub_prod.marketSegments', 'sub_seg');
>
>    // to match children of main query's DIRECT CHILD
>    // they need to have left and right values between DIRECT CHILD's left and right
>    $sqb->where(
>             $sqb->expr()->andX(
>                $sqb->expr()->gt('sub.lft', $qb->getRootAlias().'.lft'),
>                $sqb->expr()->lt('sub.rgt', $qb->getRootAlias().'.rgt'),
>                $sqb->expr()->eq('sub.root', $qb->getRootAlias().'.root')
>         ));
>
>    // match only children with products related to $segment
>    $sqb->andWhere($sqb->expr()->eq('sub_seg.id', ':segment_id'));
>
>    // BACK TO MAIN QUERY
>    // select only parentNode children THAT
>    $qb->andWhere(
>          $qb->expr()->orX(
>              // contain product with related segment
>              $qb->expr()->eq('seg.id', ':segment_id'),
>              // or 
>              // have a child (direct or indirect) that does contain such product
>              $qb->expr()->exists($sqb->getDQL())       
>      ))
>      ->setParameter('segment_id', $segment->getId());
>
>    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
> ```
>
> }